# GridView to add Delete column dynamically (Server Side)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

We read from XML and create columns in asp gridview. Also same XML is used to create columns in a data table. We populate that data table with desired data and bind data table to gridview using server side code.

Now, we want to add delete link in each gridview row and not sure how to manage it. Since we are not using RowDataBound method.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Lot of solution exists for this problem. 
Example the delete the row from the datasource (`DataSource.RemoveCurrent`).

If you can define the "delete button row" (type button) you can use a simple `dataGridView1.Rows.Remove` .

Or if you want to delete the row with a simple click on the button:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)  {
       if (e.ColumnIndex == 8)// define the delete button column
       {
             dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]); // delete with index!
        } }
```